# Make failed : make: *** [sub-corelib-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling

I am using the Ubuntu 14.04 in virtual box and 64 bit OS

I try to cross compile Qt-everywhere 4.8.6 with a 'gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7'  cross compiler and get the following error while doing the 'make'

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6
/src/corelib'
/usr/local/linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (The path depends where the Toolchain has been installed) -c -pipe -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DHB_EXPORT=Q_CORE_EXPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I../../mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-linaro-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtCore -I.rcc/release-static-emb-arm -Iglobal -I../3rdparty/zlib -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -I../3rdparty/md5 -I../3rdparty/md4 -I.moc/release-static-emb-arm -o .obj/release-static-emb-arm/adler32.o ../3rdparty/zlib/adler32.c
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make[1]: *** [.obj/release-static-emb-arm/adler32.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/src/corelib'
make: *** [sub-corelib-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

The .configure script has no problems

Can anyone help out, what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

This text doesn't belong in your call to gcc:

```
(The path depends where the Toolchain has been installed)
```

Remove that to get rid of the error.

Comment: `/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/src/corelib' this is the path you are pointing ryt?

If so from **make** I need to remove or how?

Can you explain what to remove and where to remove.

Comment: No, remove that exact text from this line: /usr/local/linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (The path depends where the Toolchain has been installed) -c -pipe -O3 -march=armv7-a ...